# Error "HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext" no contiene una definición para "ChallengeWith"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Estoy Realizando este [tutorial](https://code-adda.com/2019/01/jwt-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api/) para aprender un poco jwt, pero me sale un error:

> "HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext" no contiene una definición para
>   "ChallengeWith" ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión
>   "ChallengeWith" accesible que acepte un primer argumento del tipo
>   "HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext"

estoy utilizando .net framework 4.6 
en el metodo challenge the la clase JwtAuthentication
sale el error mencionado ...

```
        private void Challenge(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context)
    {
        string parameter = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Realm))
            parameter = "realm=\"" + Realm + "\"";

        context.**ChallengeWith**("Bearer", parameter);
    }
```

me pueden explicar esto o entre versiones de .net framework cambio algo?

Comment: Hola, si estás aprendiendo JWT en .NET Framework 4.6, te recomiendo leas este artículo [JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API 2 de ASP.NET](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/6/17/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-2-de-aspnet)

Comment: hola @RafaelAcosta como estas? pues si ya realice el tutorial de tu pagina pero no entiendo la parte donde haces un DelegatingHandler, en el tutorial mencionado no utiliza el DelegatingHandler, gracias nuevamente.